# How can I change the size of the labels of a diagram made with tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, diagrams, tikz-cd

I am writing a LaTeX document with lots of diagrams, however, I just found out their labels are too small to be read. For example, take a look at the diagram

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
        0 \arrow[r] & C_{\bullet} \arrow[d,"\gamma"] \arrow[r,"F"] & D_{\bullet} \arrow[d,"\delta"] \arrow[r,"G"] & E_{\bullet} \arrow[d,"\epsilon"] \arrow[r] & 0\\
        0 \arrow[r] & C'_{\bullet} \arrow[r,"F"] & D'_{\bullet} \arrow[r,"G"] & E'_{\bullet} \arrow[r] & 0\\
    \end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

The general settings of the document are given by

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
```

And I would simply like to view F,G,\gamma,\delta and \epsilon as regular mathmode letters, with their usual shape and size.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to add `every label/.append style={font=\normalsize}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large,every label/.append
style={font=\normalsize}]
        0 \arrow[r] & C_{\bullet} \arrow[d,"\gamma"] \arrow[r,"F"] & D_{\bullet} \arrow[d,"\delta"] \arrow[r,"G"] & E_{\bullet} \arrow[d,"\epsilon"] \arrow[r] & 0\\
        0 \arrow[r] & C'_{\bullet} \arrow[r,"F"] & D'_{\bullet} \arrow[r,"G"] & E'_{\bullet} \arrow[r] & 0\\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to apply this to all your diagrams, use

```
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style={font=\normalsize}}
```

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style={font=\normalsize}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
        0 \arrow[r] & C_{\bullet} \arrow[d,"\gamma"] \arrow[r,"F"] & D_{\bullet} \arrow[d,"\delta"] \arrow[r,"G"] & E_{\bullet} \arrow[d,"\epsilon"] \arrow[r] & 0\\
        0 \arrow[r] & C'_{\bullet} \arrow[r,"F"] & D'_{\bullet} \arrow[r,"G"] & E'_{\bullet} \arrow[r] & 0\\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I add that command somewhere else so that it can be applied to all my existing diagrams?

Comment: @Akerbeltz Sure. I added the relevant command to the answer.